# Dimension of commuting symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be a subspace of all $11* 11$ real matrices such that (i) every matrix in $S$ is symmetric and (ii) $S$ is closed under matrix multiplication. What is the maximum possible dimension of $S$.

Comment: If $A,B\in S$, then also $AB\in S$. In particular, $AB$ is symmetric, i.e., $AB = (AB)^T = B^TA^T = BA$. Hence, all the matrices in $S$ must commute with each other. One possible space is the $11$-dimensional space of diagonal matrices.

Comment: Yes. But they have asked maximum possible dimension.

Comment: It is not clear to me. Please explain.

Comment: What is not clear to you?

Comment: How can you claim that 11 is maximum possible dimension of S.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a subspace as in the question.

> First claim: $S$ is the span of orthogonal projections.

Indeed, let $A\in S$. Then $A = \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iP_i$, where the $\lambda_i$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $A$ and $P_i$ is the orthogonal projection onto the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_i$. Now, each $A^n\in S$ and thus also $p(A)\in S$ for every polynomial $p$. We have $p(A) = \sum_{i=1}^mp(\lambda_i)P_i$. Choosing a polynomial $p_k$ such that $p_k(\lambda_i) = \delta_{ik}$ for all $i$, we find that $P_k = p_k(A)\in S$. So, $A\in\operatorname{span}_iP_i$ and $P_i\in S$. If $\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$ is a basis of $S$ and $P_{ij}$ ($i\in I_j$) are the eigenprojections for $A_j$, we find that $S = \operatorname{span}\{P_{ij} : j\le n,\,i\in I_j\}$.

Now, let $S = \operatorname{span}\{P_1,\ldots,P_n\}$ be a basis of $S$ consisting of orthogonal projections. Then, for any $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ the matrix $P_iP_j$ belongs to $S$ and is thus symmetric, that is, $P_iP_j = (P_iP_j)^T = P_j^TP_i^T = P_jP_i$. But $P_iP_j = P_jP_i$ means that $P_iP_j = P_i$ or $P_iP_j=P_j$ or $P_iP_j=0$. Let us write $P_i\le P_j$ if $P_iP_j = P_i$ and $P_i\perp P_j$ if $P_iP_j=0$. Note that $\le$ is transitive and that $P\le Q$ and $Q\perp R$ implies $P\perp R$.

Now, there exists some $k$ such that for all $j\neq k$ we have $P_k\le P_j$ or $P_k\perp P_j$. After reordering we may assume that $k=1$. Now, set $Q_1 = P_1$, $Q_j = P_j-P_1$ if $P_1\le P_j$, and $Q_j = P_j$ if $P_j\perp P_1$. Then $Q_1\perp Q_j$ for all $j\ge 2$. Let us see that the $Q_j$ remain linearly independent. For this, let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb R$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j Q_j = 0$. Mulitplying this with $Q_1$ we see that $\lambda_1=0$. Hence,
$$
0 = \sum_{j=2}^n\lambda_j Q_j = \sum_{P_1\le P_j}\lambda_j(P_j-P_1) + \sum_{P_1\perp P_j}\lambda_j P_j = -\left(\sum_{P_1\le P_j}\lambda_j\right)P_1 + \sum_{j=2}^n\lambda_j P_j,
$$
implying $\lambda_2=\ldots=\lambda_n=0$.

By induction, we find a basis $\{P_1',\ldots,P_n'\}$ of $S$ such that $P_i'P_j'=0$ for all $i\neq j$. If $B_i$ is an orthonormal basis of the image of $P_i'$, then $B = \bigcup_{i=1}^nB_i$ is an orthonormal system in $\mathbb R^{11}$. Thus,
$$
11\ge |B| = \sum_{i=1}^n|B_i|\ge \sum_{i=1}^n\,1 = n = \dim S.
$$
So, the maximal dimension of such a subspace equals $11$, and the set consisting of the diagonal matrices is such an $11$-dimensional subspace.

Comment: The matrices commute and are diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$. Then (even for an infinity of matrices) all these matrice are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: @loupblanc This is a nice argument (which I didn't take into account) but uses a non-trivial result. Or is it easy to show this for finitely many matrices?

Comment: cf. the answer I just wrote in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822605/simultaneous-orthogonal-diagonalization/3386015#3386015

Comment: @loupblanc This is a very nice and simple proof. Thank you! Maybe one could add there that conjugating with some matrix $Q_k$ in the $k$-th eigenspace does not do anything to $B$ since $B = \mu_k\cdot I$ there.